# Is "commute to" acceptable?

Tags: prepositions

Is it acceptable to say "I commute to San Francisco every morning" or is there  the "to" a problem there?

Comment: Please explain why you consider there might be a problem.

Comment: The word "to" sounds a little bit weird to me there.

Comment: That is **not** an *explanation*!  Please refer to the **Help** pages about asking questions on this site and/or consider whether the **English Language Learners** site at http://ell.stackexchange.com/ might be more suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a must to use **to** with *commute*, when the word *commute* is used by the means of travel and if you are indicating a destination.

> We are also looking at people travelling, **commuting to** Dublin to
>   ascertain the traffic flows, he said.

Answer (score 3):

You must use **to** in this construction.

*Commute,* as used here, is an intransitive verb (source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commute)), so it takes no direct object. You can add a prepositional phrase, such as

- I commute **to** New York,
- I commute **from** New Jersey,
- I commute **by** train,

but the preposition is mandatory.